# Knowning at which point we are in a foreach

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$array=array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2','value3');
```

and a foreach:

```
foreach($array as $v){
     //do something
}
```

Is there a way to know in the foreach which element we are parsing?

(without doing something like:)

```
$count=0;
foreach($array as $v){
    $count++;
    // do something
}
```

thanks

EDIT1:

Sorry maybe I was not clear:
I don't want know the key, but I need to know how many elements are left in the foreach. (that's why I did the example with $count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sort of.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) 
//  code
}
```

$key will be the array key, although if you want an actual integer count of iterations, and the keys are not numbered sequentially, or are strings, you will have to use a counter like in your original post.

Edit: to handle the last element without implementing a counter, you can use (if keys are int)

```
 $foo = ($key == count($array)-1) ? "last element" : "any other element";
```

(janked from the manual comments - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Edit: if your keys are not integers, you can create a counter like you have in your code above, and substitute $key with your counter variable.

Comment: then you must implement a count like you have in your post :) (unless you only need to know if it is the last)

Comment: $foo = ($current_key == count($array)-1) ? "last element" : "any other element";

Comment: $keys are string not integer :)

Comment: Ah, bah. Wasn't thinking. Yep, going to need a counter.

Comment: would be that possible with iterator?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.. just substitute $current_key with your counter, make sure you don't have an off by 1

Comment: Thanks for the check, much obliged. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a class that extends [*ArrayIterator*](http://php.net/class.arrayiterator):

```
class FooArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator {
    private $offset = 0;
    public function next() {
        $this->offset++;
        return parent::next();
    }
    public function rewind() {
        $this->offset = 0;
        parent::rewind();
    }
    public function seek($offset) {
        if ($offset >= 0 && $offset < $this->count()) {
            $this->offset = $offset;
        }
        parent::seek($offset);
    }
    public function offset() {
        return $this->offset;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$array = array('value1','value2','value3');
$iter = new FooArrayIterator($array);
foreach ($iter as $v) {
    echo ($iter->count() - $iter->offset() - 1).' more';
}
```

Comment: Hm wow! I am so much used to php procedure style i don't even get what those code mean.

Comment: Can I know why did you redefined seek and rewind? (are them automatically used by foreach?)

Comment: Just one note: this FooArrayIterator it's just a $count++ version but more elegant :) That's why I would discorage using it over the simple example i made in the first post, anyway +1 is the least!

Comment: @yes123: The internal `$offset` needs to be updated when the offset is changed by one of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the actual index:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
}
```

If you are working with an associative array there is no way to tell the current position of the internal array pointer. There is only an indirect way: you search for the current key in the keys of the array with:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    $position = array_search ($index, array_keys ($array));
    echo ($position);
}
```

... but I guess `count++` is a much more resource-friendly way.

Comment: Modified the answer according to your edit. I guess this is as close as you can get to the the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can:


$count = count($array);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
 $count--;

 //$count elements are left 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're being a bit too picky :)

By the way the trick is to transform an associative array to an indexed array:

```
foreach ( array_values($array) as $key=>$value ){
    echo $key; //yes, it will be an INT
    echo ( count($array) - $key );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `count()` at each iteration.

Comment: it can be saved in a var and moved out. the concept still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Without some pre-processing, such as your `count()` version, there isn't any way to know where you are in an associative array. At most you can check if you're at the end with [`end()`](http://php.net/end), but there's no guarantee as to what order foreach() will retrieve the individual elements. Generally it's the same order they got added to the array, but not guarantees.

Another pre-processing option would be

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$cnt = count($keys)
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
     $element = $array[$keys[$i]];
}
```

and $i would tell you exactly how far through you've gone.